# Push string to array if the array you want to push from is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am not a coder, I am messing around with some JavaScript as part of modding a game, so bear with me. This game supports es5/everything Chromium 28 supported.

I had code which pushed a string to an array from a variable, and when the variable was undefined a fixed string was pushed instead:

```
       slotsArray.push({
          landing_policy: ai.landing_policy || 'no_restriction'
        });
```

The setup changed such that where ai.landing_policy was set it would contain multiple values, so it become an array. When it wasn't set only a single entry was required.

The same code does not appear to work where an array is in place:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          slotsArray.push({
            landing_policy: ai.landing_policy[i] || 'no_restriction'
          });
        }
```

An error is produced because it's trying to check a value from a variable that hasn't been defined. I expected that to cause it to use the fixed value, but apparently that's not what happens, it just fails.

I've changed my approach to the code seen below in full:

```
      if (Array.isArray(ai.landing_policy)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          slotsArray.push({
            landing_policy: ai.landing_policy[i]
          });
        }
      }
      else {
        slotsArray.push({
          landing_policy: ai.landing_policy || 'no_restriction'
        });
      }
```

This code works, but what I'm looking to understand is whether this was the best solution? The old method felt elegant, while the new one looks a little clumsy.

Comment: What is `count`, is it `ai.landing_policy.length`? Even if not, IMO your current code looks fine, its intent is quite clear and I don't think there's any clean way to make it more DRY. Also note that since you're using `Array.isArray`, that's an ES6 method (and being able to use ES6 is *great*)

Comment: Are you okay with spread syntax or arrow functions?

Comment: @CertainPerformance `var count = ai.copies || 1;` is used to set the size of the loop, though in retrospect I could just set the loop by the size of the array given the two values will always be the same (the 1 is a holdover from the failed approach). I'm surprised the es6 function works (I didn't know it was es6) as `navigator.appVersion.match(/.*Chrome\/([0-9\.]+)/)[1]` returned "28.0.1500.68", which my understanding is es5, so there must be more going on under the hood than I understand.

Comment: @adiga I don't know what either of those things are, though I'm happy to research into them. This question is driven by my using this as an excuse to learn a little more JavaScript.

Comment: I had posted an answer using `map` and ternary operator before realizing your code is much more readable. I'd keep it as it is.

Comment: As a follow-up, given count is just matching the length of the array, is it best practice to instead do `for (var i = 0; i < ai.landing_policy.length; i++) {`?

Comment: Flagged the question as opinion-based; There isn't a code-problem you are trying to solve. You should ask this on CodeReview: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Apologies, I didn’t realise there was a separate location for that sort of thing, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ternary operator(`? :`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

It will return the second value if the first is true, and the third otherwise.

I've used `array instanceof Array` instead of `Array.isArray(array)` to support ES5.

```js
var isArray = ai.landing_policy instanceof Array
for (var i = 0; i < (isArray ? count : 1); i++) {
    slotsArray.push({
        landing_policy: isArray ? ai.landing_policy[i] : ai.landing_policy || 'no_restriction'
    });
}
```

Comment: This will push items from `0` to `count` many times to the array regardless, which may not be desirable. Not sure what `count` is, though...

Comment: @CertainPerformance Good catch, I've reworked my solution, thanks!

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. If I'm understanding this correctly (after reading your link), this code checks whether ai.landing_policy is an array, then sets isArray to true or false. Then later on ? is used to evaluate whether isArray is true or false, and if true uses the first expression and if false uses the second expression. But my current code also supports landing_policy being a string, which I don't believe this code block allows for, correct? Also, how does it know which entry from the array to draw from without adding [i] to ai.landing_policy?

Comment: @Quitch I've tried to answer as quick as possible, and... as you see, I made some mistakes. You **have** to add `[i]` (as you've thought). And I've also corrected the support for string. See my answer now!

Answer (score 1):

Elegant solution not always converse to the most readable/desirable. I would probably do something like:

```
 const formattedPolicy = ai.landing_policy.map(policy => policy || 'no_restriction');
 slotsArray = [...formattedPolicy ];
```

Course this has to imply that the ai.landing_policy is always an array. If you need to double check first you could also do:

```
const formattedPollicy = ai.landing_policy.constructor === Array 
               ? ai.landing_policy.map(policy => policy || 'no_restriction');
               : [ai.landing_policy]
```

Looks like an elegant or short imho but your code is way more readable.

Comment: Thanks. As I’m not a coder myself (beyond some Pascal way back in school) I don’t really have experience with self documenting code, or the idea of what is readable vs what is not, so a lot of my thinking has just been driven by how can I do what I want to do in the least amount of code possible. I appreciate the thoughts.